# Checking if input string is a timestamp/date in java without knowing the format

Tags: java, datetime

Is there an equivalent in java to python functions that can parse date/time input without giving the format as an argument?

I want to be able to receive an input and determine if it's a time stamp of some sort. Is it necessary to manually go over all common patterns?

Answer (score 1):

[dateparser](https://github.com/sisyphsu/dateparser) is a neat utility which might fit your case